# 3 differend buttons and actions in 1 button

Tags: swift, xcode, button, action

I am trying to develop an app easy game. And in my design(using xcode swift 4.x) I have a button. But this button actually a 3 different button evert time pressed the button will change its status and action ofcourse. I tried some if - else statements but can't find any way. Any suggestion or any knowledge how to achieve this kind of code. Thanks anyway. Have a nice codes.

Code I wrote

```
    @IBAction func btnUncoverQuestion(_ sender: RoundedButton) {
    btnUncoverQuestion.setTitle(questionArray?[questionNumber].title ?? "No question here", for: .normal)
    btnState = btnState + 1
    if btnState == 1 {
        sender.setTitle("Başlat", for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.flatWhite, for: .normal)
        startTimer()

        btnState += 1

        if btnState == 2 {
            btnState = 0
            sender.setTitle("Tamam", for: .normal)
            sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.flatWhite, for: .normal)
            stopTimer()
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sizce cevap doğru mu", message: "Seçimin yap", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Doğru", style: .default, handler: { (trueAction) in
                self.playerArray[self.turn].point += 1
                self.turn += 1
                self.updateQuestionScreen(button: sender)
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yanlış", style: .default, handler: { (wrongAction) in
                self.turn += 1
                self.updateQuestionScreen(button: sender)
            }))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `if btnState == 2` statement is in the wrong block.
Also, what is `questionNumber`, when will it be incremented? How does it relate to `self.turn`?

You could try this:

```
@IBAction func btnUncoverQuestion(_ sender: RoundedButton) {
    btnUncoverQuestion.setTitle(questionArray?[questionNumber].title ?? "No question here", for: .normal)
    btnState = btnState + 1

    if btnState == 1 {
        sender.setTitle("Başlat", for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.flatWhite, for: .normal)
        startTimer()
    } else if btnState == 2 {
        btnState = 0
        sender.setTitle("Tamam", for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.flatWhite, for: .normal)
        stopTimer()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sizce cevap doğru mu", message: "Seçimin yap", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Doğru", style: .default, handler: { (trueAction) in
            self.playerArray[self.turn].point += 1
            self.turn += 1
            self.updateQuestionScreen(button: sender)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yanlış", style: .default, handler: { (wrongAction) in
            self.turn += 1
            self.updateQuestionScreen(button: sender)
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this logic in if state but didnt worked well. Means in my code I wrote something wrong hmmm... Thanks for advise

Comment: Unles you show the code, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use tag for different event.Example in 1st press you set the button.tag = 100 and 2nd press set the tag 200.

Check the tag in button action:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag {
    case 100:
        //your action
        sender.tag = 200
    case 200:
        //your action
        sender.tag = 300
    case 300:
        //your action
        sender.tag = 100
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

Hope it helps you.Thank you

Comment: There is just 1 button how can I assign different tag values ?

Comment: Yes you can set different tag for a single button. The tag value will be change on button click action